# How to retrieve ContentText from android.app.Notification object?

Tags: android, notifications

I am looking for a way to be able to retrieve the ContentText from a Notification Object. Something like the following:

```
NotificaionCompat.Builder builder;
Notification existing;
builder.setContentText(existing.ContentText);
```

I have already discovered that you can find and retrieve the tickertext. The following code does that already, for example:

```
CharSquence tickertext;
tickertext = existing.tickerText;
```

Please can you help me figure out how to solve my problem?

Thanks,

Isaac